# More and more frequent "Full GCs" with no need to collect? (In general or ActiveMQ specifically)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, activemq-classic

We have a fairly loaded ActiveMQ instance (mostly topics and around 300 connections). It initially has a GC pattern that looks ok but with time it does more and more frequent Full GCs for no apparent reason (see graph below). As seen it's not heading anywhere good.

The only explicitly set memory setting is `-Xmx4096m` so it's not like it is running out of heap. Thought it could be threads, currently it has 680 threads (270 connections) which doesn't seem very high.

Would appreciate input on why it is behaving like this and how dig further to get to the bottom of this.

[Here's a one hour excerpt from GC log](https://pastebin.com/GViYRLEm).

[image: Heap diagram]

Java command line:

```
java 
-Dactivemq.home=../.. 
-Dactivemq.base=REMOVED 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=REMOVED 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=REMOVED 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=REMOVED 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=REMOVED 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-Xloggc:/opt/activemq/active/data/gc.log 
-Xmx4096m 
-Djava.library.path=../../bin/linux
-x86
-64/ 
-classpath ../../bin/wrapper.jar:../../bin/activemq.jar 
-Dwrapper.key=REMOVED 
-Dwrapper.port=32000 
-Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 
-Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 
-Dwrapper.pid=REMOVED 
-Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 
-Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper 
-Dwrapper.service=TRUE 
-Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 
-Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.apache.activemq.console.Main start
```

ActiveMQ Version: 5.15.0

JVM Version: 1.8.0_131

*GC analysis from gceasy.io. Have no affiliation with them but liked the service.*

Comment: One reason that can happen w/ JVM is that the object life may be slightly longer than what would get picked up in the incremental gc's. Crank up the gc logging to collect more info.

Comment: indeed, detailed GC logs and JVM arguments are needed to draw any conclusions.

Comment: Alright thanks, have `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` on so got that, added a link to the last hours data to the original post. But could use help to interpret it.